# Custom Class + Database calls causing memory to rise?

Tags: ios, class, memory-management

This is piggybacking off of two earlier questions.  I'm using heapshots to check how my memory was doing before submitting to the app store, and I found that it was increasing by 3-5KB every time the user completed a loop of the program.  I went back to the drawing board, commented out large sections of the program and slowly brought the sections back online.  I was able to sort of narrow it down to what I believe is the heart of the problem.

I'll note: I converted to ARC and still had the same issue.  Here is (what I believe) is the relevant areas of code.

Row Class:

```
@interface Row : NSObject {
int rowID;
NSString *rowProblem;
NSString *rowAnswer;
int rowTimes_Right;
int rowTimes_Wrong;
Boolean marked;
}

@property (nonatomic) int rowID;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *rowProblem;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *rowAnswer;
@property (nonatomic) int rowTimes_Wrong;
@property (nonatomic) int rowTimes_Right;
@property (nonatomic) Boolean marked;
```

Database function (Gets a Row):

```
-(Row *) getRow {
Row *holder = [[[Row alloc] init] autorelease];

//Pick a random problem to give to the User
int randomrow = (arc4random() % [self getNumberOfRows]) + 1;



NSString *querysql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM problems WHERE id = %d", randomrow];

const char *sql = [querysql UTF8String];    
sqlite3_stmt *statement;

//Execute the Query
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(wordsDB, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
    {
        char *problem = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
        char *answer = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);

        holder.rowID = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
        holder.rowProblem = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:problem];
        holder.rowAnswer = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:answer];
        holder.rowTimes_Right = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 3);
        holder.rowTimes_Wrong = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 4);
        holder.marked = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 5);

    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"SQL Error Message: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(wordsDB));
}

return holder;
}
```

Tying it all together in the View:

```
-(void)setToWord{
[currentRow release];
 currentRow = [[dataB getRow] retain];

[problemLabel setText:currentRow.rowProblem];
[definitionLabel setText:currentRow.rowAnswer];
}
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Surely heapshot shows you exactly what, and when is increasing?

Comment: @hooleyhoop It does, and I asked about the specific part in an earlier question (including posting the call stack), but nobody could decipher it.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about 5KB of leakage. Apple's own Cocoa routines are leaky to this degree, and Apple clearly doesn't worry about it. For example, in a simple app of mine where we push a view controller onto a navigation controller and then later pop it off again, Instruments shows that all of my objects are correctly torn down, but there's a slight leak, clearly coming from deep inside Cocoa. You should be able to see quite clearly using Instruments whether the code generating the objects left over in each heapshot is your code. You could try wrapping the interior of your `getRow` method in `@autoreleasepool{}` but I doubt it will make any difference.

Comment: So apple wouldn't be concerned about this if I submitted my program?  Leaks doesn't find anything and neither does Analyzer, but I was worried they'd see that behind-the-scenes leak and say no.

Comment: I submitted the app I described above and there were no issues. - In fact, try this; make an app from Xcode's built-in Utility Application template and run it under Instruments. Do a heapshot that shows what happens when you flip to the modal view and flip back. You'll see a tiny leak, about 6KB. Apple's code is full of this stuff. 5KB per go-round is *tiny*! We live in a world of GB.

Comment: Apple won't reject your app for it.  It is still good to fix as memory leaks will eventually cause your app to be killed.  How soon will depend on how fast you leak memory, and how much memory you use to actually perform your task.    BTW, does leaks show the memory as leaked?   If not it could be cached objects that might get released on a memory warning.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it is often fustrating. In both your previous questions you post a detailed stack trace. This is one of the less interesting things that Instruments is showing you.

Pick any point in your program - when it runs it uses memory - this is the stack, you don't need Instruments to tell you that.

Instruments can show you the counts of all live objects in your app - what is increasing from heapshot to heapshot that shouldn't be? It's possible to accidentally have objects you think have been destroyed, hang around, leaking, but not show up in leaks because technically they are still reachable from somewhere. If you find an object that is leaking or just shouldn't exist, it isn't the stack trace for the line that created it that is important, it's why hasn't it be cleaned up? Where did you forget to release or free? Instruments will show you the retain history for each object so you can work out where you didn't balance a retain or clean up a property.

This is just basic Instruments stuff really, easily picked up even by me.

As a sidenote. Although the frameworks do sometimes very rarely have a leak, it is far more common for me to have a bug that will manifest itself in Leaks as a block of bytes being leaked deep in some framework.